# React Context Provider does not update the value when it is in a Router Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-context

```
const Context = React.createContext("initial")
```

Here is the JSX code.

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/a">
        <Context.Provider value="updated">
          <A/>
        </Context.Provider>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/b">
          <B/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Here Component A is a child of context provider. But when the Consumer takes the context, the value is still "initial".

```
    class A extends Component {
      ...
      render() {
        return (
         <Context.Consumer>
           {context => (
             <div>
                <p> value is {context}</p>
             </div> ) }
         </Context.Consumer>
       )}
```

But if the Context Provider runs before Router, Consumer gives "updated" which is fine.

```
     <Context.Provider value="updated">
       <A/>
     </Context.Provider>
     <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/a">
          <A/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/b">
          <B/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

The problem is why the value of Context is not updated to "updated" in first case

Comment: `why the value of Context is not updated to "updated"` How do you know it's not updated? Please share the code where you check that.

Comment: Updated. Can you check now.

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-darkness-04hih) i've tried the same code, but it works fine.

Comment: Happy to hear. In my case first render the Component A after that Component B renders killing the Component A. What if then